# Irreducibility of $Sym^2$ and $\Lambda ^ 2$ representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm given a representation $\Pi : \mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}))$ by $\Pi(g) = gXg^T$ (does it have a name?). Then the representations $\mathrm{Sym}^2$ and $\Lambda^2$ defined in the usual way - by restricting $\Pi$ to the set of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices, respectively.

I need to prove that each one of those representations are irreducible.

I started proving by contradiction, trying to show that each base vector will be in the subspace. So, for the symmetric representation I tried using the property of orthogonal diagonalization of symmetric matrices (for each symmetric $X$ there are $Q$ - orthogonal and $D$ diagonal, such that $X = QDQ^T$), but that path only good for real symmetric matrices, and therefore, in my case, requires to handle both the real and imaginary parts.

I'm almost sure there is a proof, that requires less technique, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Also I have pretty basic knowledge of representation theory, so maybe I'm missing something.

I'll appreciate any clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no need to write $nxn$; you can write $n\times n$.  (I changed it.)

Comment: Hermitian is to unitary for complex matrices as symmetric is to orthogonal for real matrices.

Comment: @SammyBlack According to wikipedia, this generalization doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea works without too much difficulty.  Consider $Sym^2$ first.  I'll show that any symmetric matrix is in the subrep $V$ containing the identity matrix $I$.  Acting on $I$ by elements of the form $g = \operatorname{diag}(\sqrt a_1, \ldots, \sqrt a_n)$ shows that any diagonal matrix is in $V$.  Now given any $Z = X + i Y$ symmetric, both $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric.  Then by the spectral theorem both $X$ and $Y$ are diagonalizable by symmetric matrices so that $X,Y \in V$.  Thus $Z = X+iY \in V$.

For anti-symmetric, a similar argument probably works using this decomposition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory .

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is exactly an elegant variant of what I was looking for.